# Get average rating for individual shop using mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, join

I am joining two table i.e shop table with rating table and want to fetch all shops list with individual shop rating, I have wriiten query for this but in output getting only those shops which have rating in rating table, but I want if shop don't have rating then show 0 else show as per table record.

**shop table:-**

```
id  shop name      
  1     shop_1      
  2     shop_2      
  3     shop_3      
  4     shop_4
```

**rating table**

```
id  shop_id  rating      
  1     1      3      
  2     4      2
```

**Query:**

```
$this->db->select('shop.*,shop.id as shop_id');
    $this->db->select('COALESCE(ROUND(AVG(rat.rating),1),0) as avgRate');
    $this->db->from('shop');
    $this->db->join('rating_reviews as rat', 'rat.shop=shop.id', 'left');
    $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

**current output:**

```
  id  shop_id      avgRate       
   1     1            3      
   2     4            2
```

**Expected output:**

```
 id  shop_id      avgRate     
   1     1            3     
   2     2            0           //(no rating given for this shop)    
   3     3            0           //(no rating given for this shop)       
   4     4            2
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry  I have mentioned each and everything clearly, what else should I mention now?

Comment: If I have to explain the link, it rather defeats the point of providing the link, doesn't it?

Comment: I didn't create any fiddle link, working on project so faced this issue now.

Comment: try this SELECT shop.id , shop.name FROM shop LEFT JOIN rating_reviews  ON shop.id=rating_reviews.shop_id

Comment: try my sql query please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to suggest another approach, avoiding the join completely:

```
select
  distinct id,
  (
     select coalesce(round(avg(rat.rating), 1), 0)
     from rating_reviews as rat where shop.id=rat.shop
  ) as avgRate
from shop
```

Comment: @msp Updated my query. Sorry for that. Cheers!

Comment: thanks, it's working as per expectation, but I have small doubt why we can't  use join.

Answer (score 1):

### Aggregate functions

The reason you're running into an error is that functions like `AVG | COUNT` are *aggregate functions* that is yo say that they aggregate all of the data and **typically** output a single record/result.

For example:

- Lets assume you have a table `shops` with `id` as the Primary Key
- There are 35 shops in the table
- There are no breaks in the Primary Key (e.g. it goes from 1 to 35)

The following queries will then return `1` row/result:

```
# Query                          # Output:  # FIELD_1 # FIELD_2 (second statement)
SELECT COUNT(shop.id) FROM shop             # 35
SELECT shop.id, COUNT(shop.id) FROM shop    # 1       # 35
```

Both of the above statements would return `1` result. The first simply the `count` for the number of shops (`35`) and the second would additionally output the `id` of the first shop (`1`).

**Your query** functions on the same princiiple, like `COUNT` the `AVG` function is an aggreagte function and will return `1` result/row from the query.

```
SELECT 
    shop.*, shop.id as shop_id,
    COALESCE(ROUND(AVG(rat.rating),1),0) as avgRate
FROM shop
    LEFT JOIN rating_reviews AS rat ON rat.shop=shop.id

-- Outputs: All fields from `shop` for the first shop followed by [shop_id] and [avgRate]
-- For example...
# shop.id # shop.name # shop.type   # shop_id # avgRate
# 1       # Tesco     # Supermarket # 1       # 3.5
```

There are however two ways to circumvent this behaviour:

**Using `GROUP BY`**

```
SELECT i, AVG(...) AS a FROM ... LEFT JOIN ... GROUP BY i
```

**Nested `SELECT` statements**

```
SELECT i, (SELECT AVG(...) FROM ... WHERE ...) AS a FROM ...
```

### GROUP BY

```
SELECT 
    shop.*, shop.id as shop_id,
    COALESCE(ROUND(AVG(rat.rating),1),0) as avgRate
FROM shop
    LEFT JOIN rating_reviews AS rat ON rat.shop=shop.id
GROUP BY shop.id
```

### Nested SELECTS

```
SELECT
    shop.*, shop.id as shop_id,
    (SELECT
         COALESCE(ROUND(AVG(rat.rating),1),0)
     FROM rating_reviews as rat
     WHERE rat.shop=shop.id
    ) as avgRate
FROM shop
```

Comment: I have intentionally not used group by because  full group by is creating problem  in live server and don't have authority to enable it.

Comment: @msp Sorry, but you don't have authority to enable `GROUP BY`?